# FAT32 partition incorrectly converted to NTFS

Tags: windows, partitioning, conversion, ntfs, fat32

I have a FAT32 partition. When I ran the following command:

```
C:\USERS\USER1\CONVERT D: /FS: NTFS
```

it didn't run the command, but asked me to reset my computer.

I reset the computer. After startup first `CHKDSK` was run, and then the conversion. Windows started at the end

But the drive D: doesn't open even though it is seen. When I click on the icon, the below error message is shown

> D:\ is not accessible. The volume is too fragmented to complete this operation.

The dialog title is *Location is not accessible*. Of course, the drive to fill Windows 7 shows.

How can I repair my drive?

Answer (score 3):

> But drive D: will not open.

Will not open how? It may be that the partition has been converted fine but is not assigned a drive letter.

Click Start, Run and then type `diskmgmt.msc` and see if the partition is visible and assigned a drive letter. If not, assign one.

Comment: Drive D: is seen.When I'm clicking on the icon, the window is seen below "D:\ is not accessible. The volume is too fragmented complete this operation." Window Title is "Location is not accessible".Of course, the drive to fill Windows 7 shows.

Answer (score 0):

First, **your convert command is incorrect**. It should be `convert d: /fs:ntfs`, no space between `fs:` and `NTFS`. And [convert.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/convert.html) is located at `%WINDIR%\System32` so no need to specify a full path. You shouldn't copy it to your user folder either. If D: is not a system drive and there are no programs reading/writing on that drive you can force a dismount to convert without the need to restart when convert.exe asks about that.

If that's some 3<sup>rd</sup> party conversion tool with different syntax then I don't recommend to use it because NTFS is MS' proprietary product and it's closed source so other tools may not fully understand the NTFS specs and mess up your data.

If you have typed the command correctly and the above was a typo then did you try **defragging the disk**? The error message says it all. NTFS needs some more space to store the MFT and other metadata. That's why you see that it's reported to use some space even if the drive is blank and the space consumed is always larger than FAT32. The MFT is used to store the files' information, and data if the file is small. Consequently it's supposed to be be accessed as fast as possible and should be stored in a contiguous file (or at most 2-3 fragments if the MFT needs to be expanded when the drive is nearly full).

If the drive is too fragmented to create a contiguous MFT and provide a reserved zone it may not be able to convert. Try defragging first by the windows defragmenter. If it still can't convert the drive then there may be some errors, run `chkdsk d: /f /r` with administrator rights to fix if needed. Then if there's still not enough free space you must delete some files from that drive.